# Why can't diamine oxidase be supplemented?

Tags: biochemistry, medicine

I've read from [an academic article](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2222.1993.tb00287.x) that diamine oxidase cannot be supplemented  but it had no explanation as for why. I am curious as to why this?

> Food rich in histamine or red wine may cause allergy‐like symptoms
>   such as sneezing, flush, skin itching, diarrhoea and even shortness of
>   breath. The suspected reason is a diminished histamine degradation
>   based on a deficiency of diamine oxidase. **As diamine oxidase cannot be
>   supplemented, a histamine‐free diet was implemented to reduce
>   histamine intake.**

Comment: Proteins other than hormones in general are not supplementable. Think of genetic retinitis pigmentosa, metabolic diseases etc. They are digested when taken orally and won't reach intracellular targets when injected in the bloodstream or in tissues.

Answer (score 1):

More recent research contradicts the statement that diamine oxidase (DAO) cannot be supplemented<sup>1</sup>.

This paper clearly supports use of DAO. However, Triptans like sumatriptans are typically used instead because of cost.

Note: Research is of 2018, so not your fault.

#### Reference:

1. [Izquierdo-Casas, J., Comas-Basté, O., Latorre-Moratalla, M. L., Lorente-Gascón, M., Duelo, A., Soler-Singla, L., & Vidal-Carou, M. C. (2019). Diamine oxidase (DAO) supplement reduces headache in episodic migraine patients with DAO deficiency: A randomized double-blind trial. Clinical Nutrition, 38(1), 152-158.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29475774/)

Comment: The OP's linked article clearly states that DAO can't be supplemented. I'm guessing that what you mean by "The article" is the one you linked? I've edited based on that assumption, but please correct as needed. Also, can you elaborate on the statement about triptans — it isn't clear to me how that is relevant to the original question.